# Pass existing C++ pointer to python callback using boost python

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I have an abstract C++ class, which I expose via boost python:

**expose.h:**

```
struct I {
    virtual int compute() = 0;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE( my_module )
{
    boost::python::class_< I, boost::noncopyable >( "I", boost::python::no_init )
        .def( "compute", &I::compute );
}
```

Python code to be called from c++:

**callback.py:**

```
import my_module

def MyPythonFunc(a):
     return a.compute()
```

And finally, in my main cpp code, I have a pointer which I'd like to pass to the python function:

**consume.cpp:**

```
struct B : public I {
    virtual int compute() override { return 42; }
}

B *ptr = new B;

boost::python::object main = boost::python::import( "__main__" );
boost::python::object global( main.attr( "__dict__" ) );
boost::python::object result = boost::python::exec_file( "callback.py", global, global );
boost::python::object fn = global["MyPythonFunc"];

if (!fn.is_none()) {
    // pass ptr to MyPythonFunc, ideally wrapped in a shared_ptr?
}
```

This seems as a typical scenario, however I couldn't find anything that solves it. Thanks.